# Center text on a curve, PHP GD

Tags: php, html, gd

I'm attempting to wrap text around a curve using the function found below. However, this does not take into account aligning the text centered no matter how wide the text maybe be. As an attempt to solve this problem I calculated the width of the text using a binding box.

```
$type_space=imagettfbbox($fontSize, 0, $fontname, $text);
$image_width = abs($type_space[4] - $type_space[0]) + 10;
```

However, from this, I need to work out a way that it can adjust the start `$angle`  based on the width. I've played around with lots of settings, however just can't seem to find the correct maths. Any help would be amazing, thank you!

**Curve Function**

```
function imagettftextarc($image, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $r, $color, $fontfile, $text, $dir=false){
    $sbox=imagettfbbox($size, 0, $fontfile, ' ');
    $sbox=($sbox[2]-$sbox[0])*0.1;
    $angle=$angle*M_PI/180;
    foreach(preg_split('//u', $text) AS $t){
        $px=$x+$r*cos($angle);
        $py=$y+$r*sin($angle);
        $dirangle=(360-(M_PI/2+$angle)*180/M_PI+($dir?180:0))%360;
        imagettftext($image, $size, $dirangle, $px, $py, $color, $fontfile, $t);
        $box=imagettfbbox($size, 0, $fontfile, $t);
        $dx=$box[2]-$box[0];
        $da=abs(asin(($dx+$sbox)/$r));
        if($dir){
            $angle-=$da;
        }else{
            $angle+=$da;
        }
    }
}
```

**Possible Solution**
I'm not sure how to execute this but the possibility could be to work out the length of the curve if it was a full 360 circle unwrapped horizontally. Then divide the new width with the unwrapped width to create the value that correlates to how many degrees it needs to be altered.